# redis: atomic LPOP and SADD possible?

Tags: list, queue, redis, set

Is there anyway to atomically pop an item from a list and add it to a set?

My case scenario is that I have a "work queue" list of unique items, and I want to track what's being worked on in a "in progress" set.  This would also allow the items in the "in progress" set to be re-queued if my worker process crashes while working on an item.

I'd prefer it to be atomic so that anything popped from the list will always be in the set.  I just can't figure out how to do this with MULTI/EXEC, ie:

```
redis> MULTI
OK
redis> LPOP workqueue
"foobar"
redis> SADD inprog "foobar"
redis> EXEC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you want your "in progress" collection be a Set? You could simply use a List for the in progress items.

The command [RPOPLPUSH](http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush) "Right Pop, Left Push" was made exactly for this use case.

> Atomically returns and removes the last element (tail) of the list
>   stored at source, and pushes the element at the first element (head)
>   of the list stored at destination

If you do want to use a Set for your in progress items, you will have to use a lua script and call it using [eval](http://redis.io/commands/eval).

Comment: Because a set seemed like the more appropriate data structure. As I could potentially have multiple worker processes adding to the "in progress" structure, I figured completing/removing items from an "in progress" list would more difficult and less efficient (ie. dynamic indexes as items pushed/popped).  But I just noticed the LREM command for lists, which will work because all my items are unique.  However, it is still less efficient for removing an item: SREM is O(1) in this case, LREM is O(n) where n is the length of the list.

Comment: +1 That's a great reason. Since your in-progress list is bounded, the O(n) shouldn't matter at all, its not going to be expensive. And I might add, a small set of integers will actually have O(log N) time complexity because it is implemented as an integer set. But these will simply not matter in practice, because the list or set is bounded.

Comment: @SripathiKrishnan a use-case for sets as a storage for queued messages is when the messages can benefit from being deduplicated -- for example duplicate cache-warming request messages can be processed only once and some useless processing is skipped.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that MULTI/EXEC won't work because the second command depends on the return value of the first, but neither of the commands are executed until EXEC is called. If you are using Redis 2.6 (currently in RC), you might be able to use a lua script through [eval](http://redis.io/commands/eval).

In general, I don't think atomicity is that much of a concern here. There aren't really race conditions in this case. The only bad thing that could happen is if the server crashes in the time between popping the item off the queue and adding it to the set, which seems rather unlikely.

Comment: Agree on the multi/exec and eval part of the answer. But I disagree that atomicity isn't a concern. You will have race conditions if there are multiple clients trying to push/pop in parallel. The bug will be extremely difficult to track down.